# How to take first file name from a folder in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the first file name from a folder. How can I get this in C#?

The code below returns all the file names:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(imgfolderPath);
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
{
    if (fi.Name != "." && fi.Name != ".." && fi.Name != "Thumbs.db")
    {
        string fileName = fi.Name;
        string fullFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4);

         MessageBox.Show(fullFileName);
    }
}
```

I need the first file name.

Comment: If you accept some of the answers to your other questions, people are going to be more likely to help you.

Comment: A better title might be something like: "How to find a filename that matches a predicate from a folder in C#"

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: What qualifies as the "first" file? The oldest file? The file with the "lowest" alphabetical name?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a few ways you could do this:

- You could add a `break` statement after handling the first file. This will exit the foreach loop.
- [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx) returns an array so you can assign it to a variable and scan through the elements until you find a suitable element.
- Or if you are using .NET 3.5 you could look at the [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) method with a predicate.

Here's some code:

```
string firstFileName =
    di.GetFiles()
      .Select(fi => fi.Name)
      .FirstOrDefault(name => name != "Thumbs.db");
```

Comment: oh thanks..but i was trying to declare array and blay bala..
anyway thanks

Comment: Given that `GetFiles` enumerates all files in the directory in order to create an array, it would be more efficient to use `EnumerateFiles` in this case. For more info, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9):

If you are using .Net 4.0 you should do this instead...

```
var firstFileName = di.EnumerateFiles()
                      .Select(f => f.Name)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

... `.GetFiles()` creates an array and as such must scan all files.  `.EnumerateFiles()` will return an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` so it doesn't have to do as much work.  You probably won't notice mush of a difference on a local hard drive with a small number of files.  But a network share, thumb drive/memory card, or huge number of files would make this obvious.

Comment: What?  If you are looking for a particular file add the search string.  if you are just doing a blanket get first file then if that's `thumbs.db` then that's just it.  Either way `.EnumerateFiles(...)` will only return files one at a time which is really helpfull in directories with tons of files and folders.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi. You are right.
I using this solution => http://stackoverflow.com/a/2912435/1395101 but not interesting ?!     
because may be returned "*.any file extension" and i need code returned first only for example .jpg file .    
at the end i found this solution =>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3152180/1395101

Comment: You wil still want to use `.EnumerateFiles(...)` if you are using .Net 4.0 or greater.

Answer (score 4):

```
FileInfo fi = di.GetFiles()[0];
```

Notes:

- The code throws an exception if there are no files.
- "First" is ambiguous — do you mean any file, or the first one alphabetically? In the latter case, you may need to worry about stuff like case-sensitivity and locale-dependent sorting.

Answer (score 2):

In reply to riad's comment to me:

In addition to abatischchev's solution:

```
var file = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TestFolder", "*.*")
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f != @"C:\TestFolder\Text1.txt");
```

I would add this to get the name only:

```
Console.WriteLine(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\')  + 1));
```

Which generates the output `Text2.txt` (I have three text tiles in that folder called Text1.txt, Text2.txt and text3.txt.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

var firstFile = Path.GetFileName(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dir", "*.*")
    .FirstOrDefault(f => !String.Equals(
        Path.GetFileName(f),
        "Thumbs.db",
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to supply the full path to the lambda to get the Where clause to work? Just curious? :)

Comment: Note: You don't need a separate call to Where - FirstOrDefault can accept a predicate.

Comment: True, @Mark Byers, and I don't think the above code does what is required or am I missunderstanding something? Directory.GetFiles() returns a string containing the full paths as the file names, so you would need to take that into account in the predicate as well.

Comment: @Mark: `GetFiles` return `string[]`.

Comment: Yes daft you rite.its return the full path of .I just need the first file name.Could you pls guide me how can i get the only first file name?

Comment: @abatishchev: Sorry, you're right, it doesn't return FileInfo because you used Directory instead of DirectoryInfo.

Comment: is their any way to get the first file name..pls provide me the code

Comment: @riad: I edited my answer to omit path and take only file's name

Comment: @abatishchev:sorry bro..its still return the full path.I just need the file name only..any other way???

Comment: @riad: Oops! Just forgot to add `Path.GetFileName()` to resulting file path