# What is the best way of searching a files with specific extension in another group of files

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a search algoritham for searching files having extension .txt(the occurance of all .txt file) in another group of files.ie i have a directory named d:\myfolder.I have a files of extension .txt in this folderin  as well as subfolders.
There are also files of extension .proj,.dat,.cs etc in this folder as well as subfolders.I want to search the occurance of .txt files in these files
I thought to create a list(LISTA) that contain the names of all .txt files and also create a seperate list(ListB) containg the fullpath of all other files.Then iterate throgh the 
lists to get the result.Is that a better method.Else is there any other better method

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152157/find-a-file-with-a-certain-extension-in-folder

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for a particular file in folder and sub folder then easiest would be to use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
string path = @"C:\YourFolder";
string[] txtFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, 
                                                 "*.txt", 
                                                SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You don't have to populate two different lists, one with `txt` extensions and one without. `Directory.GetFiles` would let you find all the `txt` files in a folder and sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you use LINQ:

```
 List<FileInfo> list = new List<FileInfo>();
            list= list.Where(a => a.Extension == Path.GetExtension(a.FullName)).ToList();
```