# Count specific files from folder

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
    }
}
```

This counts number of files in folder. But I need count for only specific files which are in folder such a `.txt` or `.mp3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a file with a certain extension in folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152157/find-a-file-with-a-certain-extension-in-folder)

Comment: If you prefix your code with 4 spaces, it will format nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *union* the different extensions:

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.txt")
          .Union(Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.mp3"))
          .ToArray();
```

you can chain as many `Union` as you want. In case you just want to *count* the files you don't have to use any *array*:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    MessageBox.Show(Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.txt")
             .Union(Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.mp3"))
             .Count(), 
      "Message")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/temp");

di.GetFiles("test?.txt").Length;
```

or

```
di.GetFiles("*.txt").Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the files' extensions are in your specified collection:

```
 var validExts = new []{".txt", ".mp3"};

 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
            .Where(f => validExts.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f)))
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: `HashSet<String>` for `validExts` instead of `String[]` IMHO looks better.

Comment: sure that's better.  But the change is probably insignificant on this scale.