# Get string (file name) of a given extension from within a text file

Tags: c#, string, file, text

I apologize if the question title is a little confusing, but let's say a text file contains the following data:

```
Sample         'Line1
 1             'Line2
 2             'ProjectCount
FileA.ext      'Projects( 1)
 0             'SortTermCount
FileB.ext      'Projects( 2)
 0             'SortTermCount
 ...
```

I know the extension name that exists as a string within the file (i.e. .doc), what I would like to do is get the full name and the extension of the file, the code would return "FileA.ext" and "FileB.ext" (as a string, or array (*preferably*), or whatever).

I tried to modify code from this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152180 to work with text files, but I guess that is only for directories.

**EDIT: The value before 'ProjectCount' tell me how many extension files I can expect, so perhaps I don't need to search the entire file?**

Comment: Is the filename always in the beginning of the line, followed by space?

Comment: And do all the other lines always start with a space?

Comment: @Alioza From looking at various files, it appears to be that way. So would I just read line by line, split it up, and check if the first index is an extension file? Is there a faster way?

Comment: @DavidG the numbers begin with a space, but regular text starts without a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the extensions that can show up you can use the following solution with a regex:

```
//regex for file name with known extensions    
Regex r = new Regex("^.*\\.(ext|doc|PUT_OTHER_EXTENSIONS_HERE)$");
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FILE_PATH);
var res = lines.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && r.Match(GetFirstEntry(x)).Success)
                    .Select(x => GetFirstEntry(x));
```

where GetFirstEntry :

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Splits the string by the "'" char and gets the first entry.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="x"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private static string GetFirstEntry(string x)
            {
             try{
                return x.Split(new string[] { "'" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Trim();
                }catch{return string.Empty;}
            }
```

Comment: For last line (Select.(x.Split...)), it says 'x' does not exist in current context.

Comment: Is there a way we can make this code more readable (similar to David's, but I guess some regex can get dirty)? :D If not, perhaps add some comments?

Comment: You should have kept your first answer as well. Currently it says lines is not in the context.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var fileName = @"C:\source.txt";
var files = File
    .ReadAllLines(fileName)
    .Where(line => !line.StartsWith(" "))
    .Skip(1) //Ignore the first line
    .Select(line => line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" ")));
```

Now `files` contains an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all of your file names.

So you can loop through the filenames like this:

```
foreach(string fileName in files)
{
    //fileName is a string variable

}
```

Comment: Should I change first var to string, and second to an array of strings?

Comment: You could change first `var` to `string` and the second to `IEnumerable<string>` but there's no need.

Comment: How will I get an output/access to the file names?

Comment: I've added an example, it's just a simple loop, or you could convert it to a string array with `files.ToArray()`

Comment: With your code, I get the file names, but it also prints some extra stuff: FileA.ext
FileB.ext
FileC.ext
FileD.ext
default
default
default
default
none
False
False
False
False

Comment: Perhaps because you are printing the first index of lines without spaces, instead of the extension files?

Comment: If you can modify your code to add the extension check, while still keeping the code clean (like now), your answer will be selected as it is currently the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

- Use [`File.ReadLines`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807667/get-string-file-name-of-a-given-extension-from-within-a-text-file/30808125#30808125) to read each file line by line, instead of loading everything in the memory
- Split each line on white space character
- Consider first column of split as possible file name
- Use [`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get file's extension
- Compare it against your `extensionToCheck` with ignoring case
- Select those matching

Like:

```
string extensionToCheck = ".ext";
string filePath = @"test.txt";
var fileNames = File.ReadLines(filePath)
    .Select(line => new {PossibleFile = line.Split().First()})
    .Where(p =>
        Path.GetExtension(p.PossibleFile)
            .Equals(extensionToCheck, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(f => f.PossibleFile);
```

For output use:

```
foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileNames);
}
```

In case of above sample file you will get two records

```
FileA.ext
FileB.ext
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to the code? Edit: I think the ones at the top are sufficient :)

Comment: @MohammadAli, each step is explained in the bullets before, If you have any particular question about a particular part of code then ask