# C# Get a file with a specific and exactly matching extension

Tags: c#

I know that this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152157/find-a-file-with-a-certain-extension-in-folder) exists, but the answer is not completely correct.
I have a folder and want to get all file names which have an extension `.DOC`. But there are also files in the directory with the extension `.DOCX` which I don't want in the returned value.
But by using `string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.DOC")` I get both of them while I am searching for only the `.DOC` files. 
Thus, currently I am reading both and using an `if` statement to filter the filenames again:

```
foreach (var originfile in files)
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(originfile).ToUpper() == ".DOC")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I wanted to ask if there is any possibility to get only the `.DOC` files with `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_) states that it is not possible to use regular expressions.

Comment: `is any possibility to get only the .DOC files with System.IO.Directory.GetFiles.` No, there isn't. @Rango's suggestion is the best you are likely to get.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation you linked:

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern (for
>   example, "*.txt"), the matching behavior varies depending on the
>   length of the specified file extension. A searchPattern with a file
>   extension of exactly three characters returns files with an extension
>   of three or more characters, where the first three characters match
>   the file extension specified in the searchPattern. A searchPattern
>   with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters
>   returns only files with extensions of exactly that length that match
>   the file extension specified in the searchPattern. When using the
>   question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that
>   match the specified file extension. For example, given two files in a
>   directory, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", a search pattern of
>   "file?.txt" returns only the first file, while a search pattern of
>   "file*.txt" returns both files.

So if you're using the `*` wildcard, then it's not possible, and you must do the way you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a `System.Linq` query to get what you want like

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.DOC")
                 .Select(x => Path.GetExtension(x).ToUpper() == ".DOC")
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question. It's just another way of doing what he already did