# How to read a file from local path using C# without specifying the filename and also it should read files with .csv,.xml extensions only?

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

ReadAllFiles(@"../../","names.txt");
I tried this so I am able to read the file.But what I want is to read a file without giving filename and it should read only file with some particular extension like .csv, .xml only

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152157/find-a-file-with-a-certain-extension-in-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can read like this. you have to give folder path and the pattern of you want to read the file.You can use `GetFiles` method also.

```
string path = "";
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt"))
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```