# C# save files in an array

Tags: c#

I've got a question. I want to save all TXT Files of a directory in an Array. But how should I do it ?

```
System.IO.File[] files = System.IO.File(DESKTOP_PATH);
```

(...) doesn't work.
Can anyone help me? How do I search for ONLY TXT files ?

Greetings from the US

Comment: Why tag this with WPF?

Comment: you want to save what? txt names? with full path or without?

Comment: You want to save the file paths, or their contents to an array?

Answer (score -1):

string[] files =
Directory.GetFiles(Path);

Comment: `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");` is the answer in a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152157/find-a-file-with-a-certain-extension-in-folder)

Comment: The question literally has that part in all caps: *"How do I search for ONLY TXT files?"* The answer you presented is a single line of unformatted code, with no additional explanation as to how to get just files of a certain extension or type. Code-only answers are generally considered low quality, and since it also doesn't answer the question, I think it's worthy of a down-vote. You're free to take the feedback and improve the answer, though!